# protect a single joomla chronoforms

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, chronoforms

I've been trying to protect a single Chronoform in a Joomla 2.5 site, using the following code

```
<?php
if (!(isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) &&
    $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == 'Shelley' && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == 'TopSecret')) {
  header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Secure Area"');
  header('Status: 401 Unauthorized');
} else {
echo "yes!";
}
?>
```

(it's just an example the login and pass). However, when the user clicks on the cancel button it proceeds anyway. I check on the resulting code and it's not altering the head information so it can redirect to the 401 page, but i haven't found a workaround this. Thanks

Comment: I'm not positive but I feel like setting headers like this has to happen sooner in php's execution cycle, and since you're including it in Joomla and then a component, headers have already been sent / received by the browser. You're probably not going to be able to do it this way. 

Why aren't you using Joomla's authentication system?

Comment: because I don't need the client/user to register or store any login information, so i would be establishing a registration system for the whole site where it's not required

Comment: Sorry - I'm sure you've already considered this but is there a reason you can't create a joomla user with the same user & pass you've got in your code above and then use Joomla's login form? no need for a full feldges per-user-per-account setup but just a single user account in joomla where you distribute the same logins as you would with the PHP Auth method.

Last idea: not sure if this is possible either but have you considered a .htaccess authentication method?